# How to display only unique values of a array as option in a select tag?

Tags: php, arrays, combobox

Consider this array:

```
$yrs = array(2015,2014,2015,2013,2015,2014);
```

I need to display only the unique value inside a combo box.

I tried:

```
print_r(array_unique($yrs));
```

But it displays it like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 2015 [1] => 2014 [3] => 2013 )
```

I need to have only 2015, 2014, 2013 inside the combo box. How can i extract only these values?

My code:

```
<?php
    $yrs = array(2015,2014,2015,2013,2015,2014);
?>

<select name="yrs">
<?php

    echo "<option>";
    echo implode(",",array_unique($yrs));  //here it displays in same option 
    echo "</option>";

?>
</select>
```

I need to get 2015 2014 2013 each in different options.

Comment: `echo implode(", ", array_unique($yrs));` and done! Also if you want us to fix your code, you have to show us your **full** and **real** code

Comment: @Rizier123 edited my question, please check it.

Comment: Ah! Now I see what you want. `array_unique()` is a good start. Read about foreach and for loop here: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php And try to figure it out yourself! If you get stuck or getting any errors, just update your question and show what you have and where you're stuck and we'll help you

Comment: @Rizier123 Thank you. I got the answer. `$yrss=array_unique($yrs);foreach ($yrss as $key=>$value)
{
echo "<option>";
echo $value;
echo "</option>";
}` This is the code i use.

Comment: Nice! If you want you can answer your own question and share it! (BTW: You may also want to set a value attribute for the option tag. Also to improve your code you may want to concatenate the strings: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answers my question:

```
$yrss=array_unique($yrs);
foreach ($yrss as $key=>$value) 
{ 
echo "<option>"; 
echo $value; 
echo "</option>"; 
}
```